# Enable scripts on SharePoint

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I want to run custom scripts on my online SharePoint site, I have also allowed users from running custom script on personal sites in SharePoint Online, It's already been more then 24 hrs but I am not yet able to execute custom scripts on my online SharePoint site. 
Please suggest me some better options for the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below powerhsell to allow custom script on other SharePoint sites:

```
 Set-SPOsite https://yoursite -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script